# For mTLS who should sign client certs

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2, tls1.3, mtls

Are the clients certificates needs to be signed by public CA's, private CA's ? I want the clients who have the cert to be able to connect with my server. If i trust public CA then all the clients whose certificate signed by public CA able to connect right?

In that case for mTLS the server need to have CA and sign the certificate of the clients it allows to connect ?
mTLS signing cert by public CA is waste ?